# Two SUM queries together

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table "Events" and a table “Slots” where Slots.SlotID = Events.MainSlot OR Events.ExtraSlot.

I need to sum the number of “Attendees” per time slot (as MainSlot and as ExtraSlot - ExtraSlot is optional)

Table "Events"

```
ID------Name----------MainSlot-------ExtraSlot-------Attendees
1-------Event1--------1 -------------n/a-------------20
2-------Event2--------1 -------------n/a-------------20
3-------Event3--------2 -------------n/a-------------40
4-------Event4--------2 -------------3---------------20
5-------Event5--------3 -------------4---------------40
6-------Event6--------3 -------------4---------------20
7-------Event7--------3 -------------4---------------10
```

Table "Slots"

```
SlotID--- Slot
1-------- 9.00-9.30
2-------- 9.30-10
3-------- 10.30-10.30
4-------- 10.30-11
```

If I query the database separately as follows:

```
         SELECT s.Slot, s.SlotID, ISNULL(SUM(e. Attendees), 0) AS Attendees1
           FROM Slots AS s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Events AS e ON e.MainSlot = s.SlotID
       GROUP BY s.Slot, s.SlotID
```

...or:

```
         SELECT s.Slot, s.SlotID, ISNULL(SUM(x.Attendees), 0) AS Attendees2 
           FROM Slots AS s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Events AS x ON x.ExtraSlot = s.SlotID 
       GROUP BY s.Slot, s.SlotID
```

I get the following, respectively:

```
SlotID ------  Attendees1
1------------- 40
2------------- 60
3------------- 70
4------------- 0

SlotID ------- Attendees2
1------------- 0
2------------- 0
3------------- 20 *correct
4------------- 70
```

Both results are correct.

However if I put the two queries together something is wrong as shows the table below

```
SELECT  s.Slot, s.SlotID, ISNULL(SUM(e.Attendees), 0) AS Attendees1,
        ISNULL(SUM(x. Attendees), 0) AS Attendees2
FROM Slots AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN
Events AS e ON e.MainSlot = s.SlotID LEFT OUTER JOIN
Events AS x ON x.ExtraSlot = s.SlotID
GROUP BY s.Slot, s.SlotID

SlotID------------- Attendees1---------- Attendees2
1-------------------40-------------------0
2-------------------60-------------------0
3-------------------70------------------60 *wrong
4-------------------0-------------------70
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not just do two subselects, summing those results together.

Comment: Hi, I'm using SQLServer.
James, How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  s.SlotId,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  SUM(attendees)
        FROM    events ea
        WHERE   ea.MainSlot = s.SlotId
        ), 0) AS AttendeesAsMain,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  SUM(attendees)
        FROM    events ea
        WHERE   ea.ExtraSlot = s.SlotId
        ), 0) AS AttendeesAsExtra
FROM    Slots s
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I will check my code and post back as soon as I find the best solution. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is something related to the fact that you have records in both for that group.  Try the following (MSSQL Server)

```
SELECT s.Slot, s.SlotID, ISNULL(SUM(e.Attendees), 0) AS Attendees1,
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN  x. Attendees IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE x.Attendees END), 0) AS Attendees2
FROM Slots AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN
Events AS e ON e.MainSlot = s.SlotID LEFT OUTER JOIN
Events AS x ON x.ExtraSlot = s.SlotID
GROUP BY s.Slot, s.SlotID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT a.SlotID, Attendees1, Attendees2 FROM
         (SELECT s.Slot, s.SlotID, ISNULL(SUM(e. Attendees), 0) AS Attendees1
           FROM Slots AS s 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Events AS e ON e.MainSlot = s.SlotID
           GROUP BY s.Slot, s.SlotID) as a,

         (SELECT s.Slot, s.SlotID, ISNULL(SUM(x.Attendees), 0) AS Attendees2 
           FROM Slots AS s 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Events AS x ON x.ExtraSlot = s.SlotID 
           GROUP BY s.Slot, s.SlotID) as b
    WHERE a.SlotID = b.SlotID
```

Answer (score 0):

You're joining twice, so you get a duplicate results in your return.  Basically you're getting this:

slotid......e.mainslot......x.extraslot.......x.attendees.....e.attendees

3...........3...............3.................20..............40
3...........3...............3.................20..............20
3...........3...............3.................20..............10

This is the expected behaviour because you're joining X to each resultant row from Slots JOIN E.